# Cannot connect to VPN Server using the SoftEther VPN client

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, softether

I set up a SoftEther VPN Server on a Windows machine. I can connect to it using the SoftEther VPN Client on multiple other machines. I recently installed the VPN Client on a new Windows machine and I'm getting an Error Code 1 - unable to connect to the server.

The new machine is using Windows Firewall and Avast Security (I added the VPN client as an exception). Any thing else I could try to get the connection happening?

Here are the VPN logs:

```
2020-04-19 17:05:40.236 ------------------------------------------------------
2020-04-19 17:05:40.236 SoftEther VPN Client Version 4.34 Build 9745   (English)
2020-04-19 17:05:40.236 Compiled 2020/04/05 23:39:56 by buildsan at crosswin
2020-04-19 17:05:40.236 The SoftEther VPN Client Engine has been started.
2020-04-19 17:05:40.434 Loading configuration file...
2020-04-19 17:05:40.435 Configuration file does not exist. Applying the initial settings.
2020-04-19 17:05:40.435 Monitoring the directory "C:\Program Files\SoftEther VPN Client". If the amount of available free disk space becomes less than 8.00 GBytes, the backup files for log files and configurations that are saved on the sub-directories of this directory will be automatically deleted in the order of oldest first. The amount of free disk space that determines when to start deletion can be modified by changing the "AutoDeleteCheckDiskFreeSpaceMin" item in the configuration file.
2020-04-19 17:06:41.847 A Virtual Network Adapter "VPN" has been created.
2020-04-19 17:08:03.871 The Virtual Network Adapter "VPN" has been deleted.
2020-04-19 17:09:51.715 A Virtual Network Adapter "VPN" has been created.
2020-04-19 17:11:59.864 The Virtual Network Adapter "VPN" has been deleted.
2020-04-19 17:23:47.844 A Virtual Network Adapter "VPN" has been created.
2020-04-19 17:28:15.326 A new VPN Connection Setting "New VPN Connection" has been created.
2020-04-19 17:28:18.012 Connection processing for VPN Connection Setting "New VPN Connection" has started.
2020-04-19 17:28:18.012 VPN Connection Setting "New VPN Connection": Connection operation starting (this is now 1 times).
2020-04-19 17:28:28.136 VPN Connection Setting "New VPN Connection": The connection has been either disconnected or it failed. Cause: Connection to the server failed. Check network connection and make sure that address and port number of destination server are correct. (code 1)
2020-04-19 17:31:08.134 Connection processing for VPN Connection Setting "New VPN Connection" has started.
2020-04-19 17:31:08.134 VPN Connection Setting "New VPN Connection": Connection operation starting (this is now 1 times).
2020-04-19 17:31:18.609 VPN Connection Setting "New VPN Connection": The connection has been either disconnected or it failed. Cause: Connection to the server failed. Check network connection and make sure that address and port number of destination server are correct. (code 1)
2020-04-19 17:34:54.548 Connection processing for VPN Connection Setting "New VPN Connection" has started.
2020-04-19 17:34:54.548 VPN Connection Setting "New VPN Connection": Connection operation starting (this is now 1 times).
2020-04-19 17:35:05.029 VPN Connection Setting "New VPN Connection": The connection has been either disconnected or it failed. Cause: Connection to the server failed. Check network connection and make sure that address and port number of destination server are correct. (code 1)
2020-04-19 17:36:09.336 The SoftEther VPN Client Engine has been shut down.
2020-04-19 17:36:09.336 ------------------------------------------------------
2020-04-19 17:39:51.099 ------------------------------------------------------
2020-04-19 17:39:51.099 SoftEther VPN Client Version 4.34 Build 9745   (English)
2020-04-19 17:39:51.099 Compiled 2020/04/05 23:39:56 by buildsan at crosswin
2020-04-19 17:39:51.099 The SoftEther VPN Client Engine has been started.
2020-04-19 17:39:51.240 Loading configuration file...
2020-04-19 17:39:51.240 Monitoring the directory "C:\Program Files\SoftEther VPN Client". If the amount of available free disk space becomes less than 8.00 GBytes, the backup files for log files and configurations that are saved on the sub-directories of this directory will be automatically deleted in the order of oldest first. The amount of free disk space that determines when to start deletion can be modified by changing the "AutoDeleteCheckDiskFreeSpaceMin" item in the configuration file.
2020-04-19 17:39:51.240 The configuration file has been loaded.
2020-04-19 17:40:45.685 Connection processing for VPN Connection Setting "New VPN Connection" has started.
2020-04-19 17:40:45.685 VPN Connection Setting "New VPN Connection": Connection operation starting (this is now 1 times).
2020-04-19 17:40:56.111 VPN Connection Setting "New VPN Connection": The connection has been either disconnected or it failed. Cause: Connection to the server failed. Check network connection and make sure that address and port number of destination server are correct. (code 1)
2020-04-19 17:46:49.216 The name of VPN Connection Setting "New VPN Connection" has been changed to "VPN".
2020-04-19 17:46:55.576 Connection processing for VPN Connection Setting "VPN" has started.
2020-04-19 17:46:55.576 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": Connection operation starting (this is now 1 times).
2020-04-19 17:47:05.702 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": The connection has been either disconnected or it failed. Cause: Connection to the server failed. Check network connection and make sure that address and port number of destination server are correct. (code 1)
2020-04-19 17:53:41.089 Connection processing for VPN Connection Setting "VPN" has started.
2020-04-19 17:53:41.089 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": Connection operation starting (this is now 1 times).
2020-04-19 17:53:51.578 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": The connection has been either disconnected or it failed. Cause: Connection to the server failed. Check network connection and make sure that address and port number of destination server are correct. (code 1)
2020-04-19 17:59:48.892 Connection processing for VPN Connection Setting "VPN" has started.
2020-04-19 17:59:48.893 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": Connection operation starting (this is now 1 times).
2020-04-19 17:59:59.391 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": The connection has been either disconnected or it failed. Cause: Connection to the server failed. Check network connection and make sure that address and port number of destination server are correct. (code 1)
2020-04-19 18:00:14.447 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": Connection operation starting (this is now 2 times).
2020-04-19 18:00:24.505 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": The connection has been either disconnected or it failed. Cause: Connection to the server failed. Check network connection and make sure that address and port number of destination server are correct. (code 1)
2020-04-19 18:00:25.916 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": Connection operation starting (this is now 3 times).
2020-04-19 18:00:27.174 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": The connection has been either disconnected or it failed. Cause: The command has been canceled by user. (code 6)
2020-04-19 18:00:51.798 Connection processing for VPN Connection Setting "VPN" has started.
2020-04-19 18:00:51.799 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": Connection operation starting (this is now 1 times).
2020-04-19 18:01:02.279 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": The connection has been either disconnected or it failed. Cause: Connection to the server failed. Check network connection and make sure that address and port number of destination server are correct. (code 1)
2020-04-19 18:04:42.770 Connection processing for VPN Connection Setting "VPN" has started.
2020-04-19 18:04:42.771 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": Connection operation starting (this is now 1 times).
2020-04-19 18:04:53.274 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": The connection has been either disconnected or it failed. Cause: Connection to the server failed. Check network connection and make sure that address and port number of destination server are correct. (code 1)
2020-04-19 18:06:02.926 Connection processing for VPN Connection Setting "VPN" has started.
2020-04-19 18:06:02.926 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": Connection operation starting (this is now 1 times).
2020-04-19 18:06:13.418 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": The connection has been either disconnected or it failed. Cause: Connection to the server failed. Check network connection and make sure that address and port number of destination server are correct. (code 1)
2020-04-19 18:15:35.029 Connection processing for VPN Connection Setting "VPN" has started.
2020-04-19 18:15:35.030 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": Connection operation starting (this is now 1 times).
2020-04-19 18:15:45.170 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": The connection has been either disconnected or it failed. Cause: Connection to the server failed. Check network connection and make sure that address and port number of destination server are correct. (code 1)
2020-04-19 18:20:10.272 The SoftEther VPN Client Engine has been shut down.
2020-04-19 18:20:10.272 ------------------------------------------------------
2020-04-19 18:20:12.396 ------------------------------------------------------
2020-04-19 18:20:12.396 SoftEther VPN Client Version 4.34 Build 9745   (English)
2020-04-19 18:20:12.396 Compiled 2020/04/05 23:39:56 by buildsan at crosswin
2020-04-19 18:20:12.396 The SoftEther VPN Client Engine has been started.
2020-04-19 18:20:12.579 Loading configuration file...
2020-04-19 18:20:12.580 Monitoring the directory "C:\Program Files\SoftEther VPN Client". If the amount of available free disk space becomes less than 8.00 GBytes, the backup files for log files and configurations that are saved on the sub-directories of this directory will be automatically deleted in the order of oldest first. The amount of free disk space that determines when to start deletion can be modified by changing the "AutoDeleteCheckDiskFreeSpaceMin" item in the configuration file.
2020-04-19 18:20:12.580 The configuration file has been loaded.
2020-04-19 18:20:24.849 Connection processing for VPN Connection Setting "VPN" has started.
2020-04-19 18:20:24.849 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": Connection operation starting (this is now 1 times).
2020-04-19 18:20:35.346 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": The connection has been either disconnected or it failed. Cause: Connection to the server failed. Check network connection and make sure that address and port number of destination server are correct. (code 1)
2020-04-19 18:45:52.329 Connection processing for VPN Connection Setting "VPN" has started.
2020-04-19 18:45:52.330 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": Connection operation starting (this is now 1 times).
2020-04-19 18:46:02.808 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": The connection has been either disconnected or it failed. Cause: Connection to the server failed. Check network connection and make sure that address and port number of destination server are correct. (code 1)
2020-04-19 18:46:17.874 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": Connection operation starting (this is now 2 times).
2020-04-19 18:46:19.240 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": The connection has been either disconnected or it failed. Cause: The command has been canceled by user. (code 6)
2020-04-19 18:49:05.742 Connection processing for VPN Connection Setting "VPN" has started.
2020-04-19 18:49:05.742 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": Connection operation starting (this is now 1 times).
2020-04-19 18:49:16.243 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": The connection has been either disconnected or it failed. Cause: Connection to the server failed. Check network connection and make sure that address and port number of destination server are correct. (code 1)
2020-04-19 19:05:29.811 Connection processing for VPN Connection Setting "VPN" has started.
2020-04-19 19:05:29.811 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": Connection operation starting (this is now 1 times).
2020-04-19 19:05:40.310 VPN Connection Setting "VPN": The connection has been either disconnected or it failed. Cause: Connection to the server failed. Check network connection and make sure that address and port number of destination server are correct. (code 1)
```

Comment: Is there a log that tells you what is going on? VPN logs are normally helpful. Is the problem computer using Wireless to connect? And then if so, is the NIC on a Public Connection (change to Private).

Comment: Hello, I added the logs, thank you for that. And the problem computer is hooked up via Ethernet.

Comment: The servers are fine - other clients connect. All clients are fine except for one. Ethernet is normally not an issue. Try updating the Ethernet driver. Uninstall the VPN client, restart and install the VPN client again. Restart again and set up the VPN client.

Comment: So I'm remoting into a series of machines and they are all having the same issue, half connected via ethernet half via wireless

Comment: From your log.  
Loading configuration file... 2020-04-19 17:05:40.435 Configuration file does not exist.  WHY?  

Adapter "VPN" has been deleted.    WHY?

New VPN Connection: ...  Cause: Connection to the server failed. Check network connection and make sure that address and port number of destination server are correct.    THIS suggests the Clients to not have the correct external Server address or possibly subnets are the same at each end.   YOU have gone from one client problem to multiple client problems. Get one client configuration working and use that on others.

Comment: I'm using the same address/port/certificate as I did on the working machines so I'm unsure why the problem machine is not working.

Comment: You would need to change the address for each machine.

Comment: @John i misspoke - by address I meant host name, ie vpn###.softether.net

Comment: @Kat In the SoftEther client properties of the connection you defined to connect to the VPN server or whatever, does the Virual Hub Name actually auto-populate? Confirm the configurations are correct. Then for whatever Port number is being used by the client, ensure there is a FW rule and an Avast security rule to allow that port outbound e.g 5555, 8888, etc...

Comment: @Kat Furthermore, you might consider uninstall the SoftEther client, reboot, and then reinstall after the reboot and ensure any installation files you execute are executed elevated as admin if applicable and you've not already done so. I would uninstall and then reinstall the client after the uninstall and reboot regardless.

Comment: And if seems the wifi network that all the problem machines are connected to is blocking VPN, going to have to speak to IT :(